# Align elements inside div using flexbox and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Here is a layout for example

[image]

How to properly align text in left&right corners and keep it responsive? Also my first rectangle doesn't stick relatively to bottom two squares.

[Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4efdfygo/6/)

Snippet from jsfiddle for them

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
     <div class="rtg vl-align">
          <img class="img" src="http://i.imgur.com/QF5zKn9.png" />
          <div class="left-corner align-self-start">
            <h4 class="h4">Left corner</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="price align-self-end">
            <h4 class="h4-price">250$</h4>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Minor note, your end tag `</h2>` does not match the start tag `<h4>`

Comment: You need `justify-content-start`, not `align-self-start`, and most likely a markup change. Read more here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#justify-content